# In MS Power Automate, how to populate dynamic property dropdown value using the result from another action?

Tags: json, power-automate

I created an action in MS Power Automation (Flow) that I want to dynamically generate the dropdown values.  I follow the documentation and examples listed here:

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/openapi-extensions#use-dynamic-values
Example:  https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors/blob/97c0317f96dc1d9601ef2d0e76f826e83bd14351/connectors/Planner/apiDefinition.swagger.json

I setup my flow exactly as described in the official documents:

```
"/MyFlow/MyAction": {
  "post": {
    "description": "This is my action",
    "operationId": "MyAction",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "description": "Please select from the dropdown",
        "in": "header",
        "name": "DropdownSelector",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "x-ms-summary": "Dropdown Selector",
        "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
          "operationId": "MyList",
          "value-collection": "list",
          "value-path": "ID",
          "value-title": "Name",
          "parameters": {
            "Filter": {
                "parameter": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "default",
        "schema": {
          "properties": {
            "Selected ID": {
              "description": "Selected ID",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Selected Name": {
              "description": "Selected Name",
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    },
    "summary": "Select from dropdown"
  }
},
```

Here is the action that the list can get it's values from:

```
"/MyFlow/MyList": {
  "post": {
    "responses": {
      "default": {
        "description": "default",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "list": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "Name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Name"
                  },
                  "ID": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ID"
                  }
                }
              },
              "description": "list"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "summary": "My List",
    "description": "My List Description",
    "operationId": "MyList",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "body",
        "in": "body",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Filter": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Filter"
            }
          },
          "required": [
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The results for my list come back in this format and I have checked and it is correct:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "Name": "Hello world",
            "ID": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Seem like everything is setup correctly, but it always show a blank dropdown, what am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my input parameter for the action to get API is incorrect.  I'll leave this question here for future references.